# Is it a good practice to annotate beans inside a custom library with @Component or @Service in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-autoconfiguration

I am creating a Spring Boot library which can be used for my main projects. Is it not a good practice to annotate beans inside a custom library with @Component or @Service in Spring Boot? If so, why?

Because I saw an article saying,

> Do not annotate each of your beans inside a library with @Component or
> @Service, but define them in an auto-configured module.

But I have 2 classes which I annotated as `@Service` and inside those 2 classes they have some beans configured as follows,

```
@Service
public class SomeClass {

private @Autowired SomeClient client;

@Bean
public SomeClient client(@Value("${some.param}) String key) {
   return new SomeClient(key);
}

public void use() {
   // use the @Autowired client and do a task
}
}
```

When I used this library as a dependency in my main project it is working fine. But I need to know what is the best practice since that article says not to do this. But if I have to configure these inside `AutoConfiguration` class it's tedious. So can anyone guide me to the correct path? Thank you.

Comment: This seems highly dependent on the specific use case and is likely to lead to opinionated answers.

Comment: @Rick Is there any bad aspect of what I am doing?

Comment: If I found a random, unsubstantiated claim in some random person's blog post, I would give it less weight than you seem to be. Their job as an author is to convince you that their approach has tangible benefits. If they don't convince you then ignore them. It's not your job to try and infer what those benefits might be.

Comment: If actual context is [this blogpost](https://piotrminkowski.com/2020/08/04/guide-to-building-spring-boot-library/), I believe the main idea was following: typically `spring-boot` starters define beans together with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotation in order to give a chance consumer to override something (looks like a typical `spring-boot` convention), and you may not use `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` together with `@Component/@Service` annotations, please read javadoc: "it is strongly recommended to use this condition on auto-configuration classes only"

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Exactly that is the post I was reading. Thank you for the response and I understand. And thank you everyone shared the ideas. I appreciate it.